# PostgreSQL update with indexed joins

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 14 for Windows on a medium sized machine.  I'm using the default settings - literally as shipped. New to PostgreSQL from MS SQL Server.

A seemingly simple statement that runs in a minute in MS is taking hours in PostgreSQL - not sure why?  I'm busy migrating over, i.e. it is the exact same data on the exact same hardware.

It's an update statement that joins a master table (roughly 1000 records) and fact table (roughly 8 million records).  I've masked the tables and exact application here, but the structure is exactly reflective of the real data.

```
CREATE TABLE public.tmaster(
   masterid SERIAL NOT NULL,
   masterfield1 character varying,
   PRIMARY KEY(masterid)
);

-- I've read that the primary key tag creates an index on that field automatically - correct?

CREATE TABLE public.tfact(
   factid SERIAL NOT NULL,
   masterid int not null,
   fieldtoupdate character varying NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(factid),
   CONSTRAINT fk_public_tfact_tmaster
      FOREIGN KEY(masterid) 
      REFERENCES public.tmaster(masterid)
);

CREATE INDEX idx_public_fact_master on public.tfact(masterid);
```

The idea is to set public.tfact.fieldtoupdate = public.tmaster.masterfield1

I've tried the following ways (all taking over an hour to complete):

```
update public.tfact b
set fieldtoupdate = c.masterfield1
from public.tmaster c
where c.masterid = b.masterid;
```

```
update public.tfact b
set fieldtoupdate = c.masterfield1
from public.tfact bb
join public.tmaster c
  on c.masterid = bb.masterid
where bb.factid = b.factid;
```

```
with t as (

    select b.factid,
            c.fieldtoupdate
    from public.tfact b
    join public.tmaster c
      on c.masterid = b.masterid
      
)
update public.tfact b
set fieldtoupdate = t.fieldtoupdate
from t
where t.factid = b.factid;
```

What am I missing?  This should take no time at all, but yet takes over an hour??
Any help is appreciated...

Comment: In Postgres you should **not** repeat the target table in the FROM clause of an UPDATE statement. So the second UPDATE statement will create a result that is larger than needed

Comment: Can we see `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the slow query?

Comment: "*This should take no time at all*" - well, you're still updating all 8 million rows of the table. But 1h is probably a bit long, yeah.

Comment: Another option would be `update public.tfact b
set fieldtoupdate = (select c.masterfield1 from public.tmaster c where c.masterid = b.masterid);` but I doubt it makes a difference compared to the first approach

Comment: "QUERY PLAN"
"Update on base b  (cost=3389.92..3287915.73 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=6537966.559..6537966.561 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=228106538 read=49973018 dirtied=45103907 written=42416543"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=3389.92..3287915.73 rows=19369600 width=20) (actual time=34.435..105296.357 rows=13329159 loops=1)"
"        Hash Cond: (b.startcalendarid = c.calendarid)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=3580 read=3038738 written=1111563"
"        ->  Seq Scan on base b  (cost=0.00..3233676.00 rows=19369600 width=10) (actual time=0.298..89226.581 rows=13329159 loops=1)"

Comment: "              Buffers: shared hit=1242 read=3038738 written=1111563"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=2805.52..2805.52 rows=46752 width=18) (actual time=33.849..33.850 rows=46752 loops=1)"
"              Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2887kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=2338"
"              ->  Seq Scan on calendar c  (cost=0.00..2805.52 rows=46752 width=18) (actual time=0.039..23.618 rows=46752 loops=1)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=2338"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=253 read=21"
"Planning Time: 24.174 ms"
"Execution Time: 6538008.053 ms"
`code`

Answer (score 0):

If the table was tightly packed to start with, there will be no room to use the HOT (Heap-only-tuple) UPDATE short cut.  Updating 8 million rows will mean inserting 8 million new rows and doing index maintenance on each one.

If your indexed columns on tfact are not clustered, this can involve large amounts of random IO, and if your RAM is small most of this may be uncached.  With slow disk, I can see why this would take a long time, maybe even much longer than an hour.

If you will be doing this on a regular basis, you should change the table's fillfactor to keep it loosely packed.

Note that the default settings are generally suited for a small machine, or at least a machine here running the database is a small one of its tasks.  But the only thing likely to effect you here is work_mem, and even that is probably not really a problem for this task.

If you use `psql`, then the command `\d+ tfact` would show you what the fillfactor is set to if it is not the default.  But note that this only applies to new tuples, not to existing ones.  To see the fill on an existing table, you would want to check the freespacemap using the extension pg_freespacemap and see that every block has about half space available.

To see if an index is well clustered, you can check the correlation column of pg_stats on the table for the leading column ("attname") of the index.

Comment: Thanks!  How would I check the fill factor and if the index is clustered?